# DataTables ssp.class.php (server processing) for PostgreSQL, add array support?

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, datatables

I have a converted ssp.class.php for PostgreSQL which works fine. However, I need to add ARRAY support to it.

I am hoping someone can give me some guidance/tips on the best way to do approach this, and/or give some example code if possible. I would appreciate it a lot.

You can get the modified file here: [ssp.class.pg.php](https://github.com/brienb/datatables-pgsql/blob/master/ssp.class.pg.php)

About DataTables server side processing: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but I found this question while searching google for an answer and wanted to post what I figured out to help the next person who might stumble upon this.

Note: I am using the referenced [ssp.class.pg.php](https://github.com/brienb/datatables-pgsql/blob/master/ssp.class.pg.php)

**My Solution - Use Heredoc**

Using heredoc, you can better define your query using array functions, inner and outer joins, subqueries etc.

In my example, I have a PostgreSQL table that contains a jsonb column named properties. I want to select the value from the last_seen key.

Using Heredoc, I define my table as a query that will return the users last seen date value as a column.

```
$table = <<<EOT
(
SELECT
id, 
unique_id, 
properties->>'last_seen' as last_seen
FROM users
WHERE token = '$token'
) temp
EOT;
```

Then, I can define my columns for the SSP PG class using the returned columns from my table query.

```
$columns = array(
            array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 'id' ),
            array( 'db' => 'unique_id', 'dt' => 'unique_id' ),
            array( 'db' => 'last_seen', 'dt' => 'last_seen' ));
```

Finally, I'll use the defined variables to call the simple function.

```
$data_result = $ssp_pg->simple($request, $conn, $table, $primaryKey, $columns);
```